Error al hacer consultas a una URL en expo (Axios Error: Network Error)
En contexto, estoy trabajando en una aplicación movil con React Native Expo, ya la tengo casi finalizada si no fuera por un error en las cosultas a los endpoint de una bdd creada de antemano, la bdd funciona bien ya que es usada para una pagina web que corre sin ningun problema.
Ahora bien, cuando ejecuto mi app por medio de expo go funciona todo bien, incluso las consultas a la bdd son correspondidas. El problema esta cuando por medio de expo.dev compilo la apk para probarla, como apk no funciona la mismas URL que en expo go si sirven.
Luego implemente en la pantalla un "comprbador de url" en el que ingrseba una url como "https:google.cl" y funciona bien, asi con varias, pero al ingresar la que me corresponde para llamar los datos que necesitos me indica "network error" tanto con el metodo de fetch como con el de axios.


Se que la url funciona ya que lo pruebo en el navegador y funciona bien:

Por favor, llevo más de dos semanas con este problema y no se que hacer.

Si estas trabajando con el servidor de manera local intenta esto:
abre la consola > escribe ipconfig > copia la dirección IPv4
Quedando: https:// tudirecciónIPv4 /index.php

Estoy trabajando con las APIs de la empresa

Encontre la solución, al final era que actualmente Android e IOs no acepta que las rutas de las APIs sean "http" debe de ser "https" o si no la bloquea, para solucionarlo se puede agragar en el manifesto de android "usesCleartextTraffic" que por defecto es "false" entonces solo se debe cambiar a "true" si quieres que acepte "http".
Para ios es algo más denso, se debe agregar lo siguiente:
"ios": {
  "infoPlist": {
    "NSAppTransportSecurity": {
      "NSExceptionDomains": {
        "example.com": {
          // Include to allow subdomains
          "NSIncludesSubdomains": true,
          // Include to allow HTTP requests
          "NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads": true,
          // Include to specify minimum TLS version
          "NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion": "TLSv1.1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Y si la aplicación la quieren subir a la appstore tengo entendido de que hay que justificar la razon de por que se usaran "http" en vez de "https".
Finalmente, la mejor opción es cambiar a HTTPS, ya que se soluciona todo los problemas para consumir las APIs y es mucho más seguro para la aplicación. Tambien se podria poner un proxy de tercero delante de la URL pero mejor es lo propio.
